# Why I see another web site at my https addres?

Tags: iis, https, webserver, plesk

Can anybody explain why I see another web site at my http secure address. I don't have a certificate. I can manage files from folder httpsdocs but cannot access them from web. Also httpsdocs is empty. https://innovacube.com/

And base of my problem is Google indexes my https domain but I cannot denny Google Bot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sharing IP addresses with another site - you'll see that both www.innovacube.com and www.cokyader.com resolve to 92.199.202.62. HTTP/1.1 allows this because you also send a host header

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.innovacube.com
```

so the web server knows which site to serve for a given connection.

It isn't, however, possible to do this for HTTPS. The problem is that the certificate negotiation happens before the server gets to HTTP so you can't switch depending on the site that the browser really means. Therefore you can only host one HTTPS site per IP and this IP is hosting cokyader.com. (There are proposed extensions to help fix this but I've never seen any progress on this.)

If you want your own separate HTTPS site then your host will have to allocate you your own separate IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using shared hosting, and it has been configured with a default SSL site that isn't yours (but presumably belongs to someone who has paid for SSL support and has their site hosted on the same server).